What role does min value and max value play in reducing memory usage?
I am learning the code from this github Intrusion Detection (CIC-IDS2017)
Here is the code and the result that the authors use to reduce the memory, but I don't know why the author made adjustments based on the maximum and minimum values?
old_memory_usage = data.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2
print(f'Initial memory usage: {old_memory_usage:.2f} MB')
for col in data.columns:
    col_type = data[col].dtype
    if col_type != object:
        c_min = data[col].min()  # <-- retrieve c_min
        c_max = data[col].max()
        # Downcasting float64 to float32
        if str(col_type).find('float') >= 0 and c_min > np.finfo(np.float32).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float32).max:
            data[col] = data[col].astype(np.float32)

        # Downcasting int64 to int32
        elif str(col_type).find('int') >= 0 and c_min > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
            data[col] = data[col].astype(np.int32)

new_memory_usage = data.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2
print(f"Final memory usage: {new_memory_usage:.2f} MB")

reference: Intrusion Detection (CIC-IDS2017)
I have tried to print the c_min and np.finfo(np.float32).min to find some roles.
Why exist numbers (np.finfo(np.float32).min) smaller than the minimum value (c_min) I have in the dataframe column?
Format:
column names ; c_min ; np.finfo(np.float32).min
Initial memory usage: 798.63 MB
Fwd Packet Length Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Fwd Packet Length Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Bwd Packet Length Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Bwd Packet Length Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Flow Bytes/s -261000000.0 -3.4028235e+38
Flow Packets/s -2000000.0 -3.4028235e+38
Flow IAT Mean -13.0 -3.4028235e+38
Flow IAT Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Fwd IAT Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Fwd IAT Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Bwd IAT Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Bwd IAT Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Fwd Packets/s 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Bwd Packets/s 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Packet Length Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Packet Length Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Packet Length Variance 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Average Packet Size 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Avg Fwd Segment Size 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Avg Bwd Segment Size 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Active Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Active Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Idle Mean 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Idle Std 0.0 -3.4028235e+38
Final memory usage: 798.63 MB

And search what is np.finfo()
Official introduction: Machine limits for floating point types

c_min and c_max in your example are just the smallest and largest numbers contained in that column of the array.  np.finfo(np.float32) returns you the absolute smallest and largest numbers that may be contained in a single-precision float.

@TimRoberts So is it possible that the array contains values ​​that exceed the interval between the absolute minimum and absolute maximum?

Assuming that the columns are of type float64 or int64, yes, they could have values that are bigger/smaller than the maximum/minimum of the 32 bit types, especially the integers. float32 can already covers a huge range and differs more in precision from float64 so I would be surprised if not all floating point columns would pass the conditional (still better to check).

@paleonix Thanks you for answer, I am understand why the values should be checked in the interval [np.finfo(np.float32).min, np.finfo(np.float32).max]. Because the author want to downcasting float64 to float32, the values maybe out of range.

A small toy example:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# A value we need float64 for
max_32 = np.finfo(np.float32).max
needs_64 = max_32 + 1000

# Downcasting would be problematic
print(needs_64.astype(np.float32))
# Output:
# <stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cast
# inf

If you have a dataframe with such a large values you cannot cast everything to float32. The script you posed makes sure that you cast only the columns that do not cause inf values.
# Dataframe with two float64 columns
df = pd.DataFrame([max_32, needs_64]).T
print(df.memory_usage().sum()) # 148

# Cast all columns to float32; you loose some values
df_float32 = df.astype(np.float32)
print(df_float32)
#              0    1
#0  3.402823e+38  inf

Note that all values in a column share the same data type, which you can check with:
df.dtypes
0    float64
1    float64

So you should only cast to float32 if your column-wise max/min values c_min/c_max are within the float32 min and max range
df_compressed = df.copy()
# cast only columns that are safe with your code
# ..., i.e. update:
df[0] = df[0].astype(np.float32)

print(df_compressed.memory_usage().sum())
# 144

print(df_compressed.dtypes)
# 0    float32
# 1    float64

# No inf value present
print(df_compressed)
#              0             1
#0  3.402823e+38  3.402823e+38

